# Enable USB Tethering Android Programmatically without user Interaction

Tags: android, tethering

I am developing an application that requires USB Tethering.

I am using the following code to do so

```
Intent tetherSettings = new Intent();
        tetherSettings.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.TetherSettings");
        startActivity(tetherSettings);
```

But this code is opening the Tethering Setting so the user can Enable the USB tethering by clicking on it. Is it possible to enable the tethering without any user interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android is very security-aware and will not enable this setting without user interaction.